# Is there any best number for rows count in a table to start using indexing?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, nonclustered-index

I'm a newbie in DBA. I want to know if there is any specified point in a table's rows count that when we reach that point, then we could use an index. I know there should be some dependency between table's rows count and using index, but I don't know if there is an standard table's rows count or not.

Comment: I don't see the dependency. Design of table (including index) depends on how the table will be used in your application.

Comment: You can always use an index, selectivity of the query matters more than number of rows in a table. If you reduce 4 IO's into 2 it's already a win if the query gets executed enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about a *best* but at a small number there is no real value.

There is some overhead to using the index.  Yes an index seek is faster than a table scan but there is some overhead to using the index.  Index maintenance clearly has overhead.

If a table has a PK then you should use that as a PK and typically clustered.

Consider a table of USstates (50 rows)

ID PK identity tinyint
Name varchar(20)
Region tinyint

Region would be use to group states like NE, SE, ...

I personally would never use indexes on Name or Region - a table scan is still very fast. Region would be a FK but that does not automatically create an index (to my understanding). The whole table is right at the 2K page size.  If sort on State.Name is used a lot then yes that index would be used but I just don't think you could even measure the performance gain.

Over a million rows then yes start building indexes up front.

Between a thousand and a million then consider building indexes on a case by case basis.

Even at 10,000 rows there are going to be a lot of cases of obvious indexes.   A column like AddDate that is not likely to change and would be used a lot for search and sort I would index and maintain (de-fragment). A table with more than 10,000 rows that reference State as a FK I would index that column up front. But since you are asking the question maybe wait and optimize for real life queries.

I would not want you to take the other extreme and put an index on every column as it *might* be used.  An index has overhead.  An index will slow down insert and update.  A highly fragment index can be slower than a table scan.

I get a lot of the users on this site want to optimize up front and have theoretical discussions.  This is real life advice for a newbie in DBA.

Comment: Agreed, except to enforce uniqueness. Might be of value then.

Answer (score 8):

An index is an on-disk structure associated with a table or view that speeds retrieval of rows from the table or view. An index contains keys built from one or more columns in the table or view. These keys are stored in a structure (B-tree) that enables SQL Server to find the row or rows associated with the key values quickly and efficiently.

> I want to know if there is any specified point in a table's rows count that when we reach that point, then we could use an index.

The rowcount in a table does not dictate the use of Index. Its your queries (pattern) that should dictate the need for creating indexes, so that the data retrieval is as fast as possible.

The query optimizer relies on statistics to produce optimal query plan.

From [SQL Server Index Design Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.120).aspx) :

> The selection of the right indexes for a database and its workload is a complex **balancing act between query speed and update cost.**
>
> Narrow indexes, or indexes with few columns in the index key, require less disk space and maintenance overhead.
>
> Wide indexes, on the other hand, cover more queries. You may have to experiment with several different designs before finding the most efficient index. Indexes can be added, modified, and dropped without affecting the database schema or application design.

You should use [SQL Server's DMV to tune your indexing strategy](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/tune-your-indexing-strategy-with-sql-server-dmvs/) or even use [sp_BlitzIndex](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/) to get more insights.

Refer to :

- [Query Tuning Fundamentals: Density, Predicates, Selectivity, and Cardinality](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2011/01/25/query-tuning-fundamentals-density-predicates-selectivity-and-cardinality/)
- [Ten Common Threats to Execution Plan Quality](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/ten-common-threats-to-execution-plan-quality)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to not use an index.

If the table is small, the cost estimator can easily deduce that a sequential scan has less overhead than an index scan followed by random access into the table data, because the index accesses are associated with a cost as well, and sequential scans also have lower cost than random access.

The only downside is that it makes `INSERT` slower -- but if that is a concern, then you are creating lots of rows.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, number of rows is no guide. Find a query that is typical for your system and execute it in SSMS with io on:

```
set statistics io on;
select * from SomeTable order by SomeColumn;
```

Look on the Messages tab, at the "logical reads" counter. This is the number of pages that need to be read to satisfy the query. (The "logical" means it does not change if the pages are already in memory.)

If it is low (say in single figures) an index is unlikely to help. If you have a test database, try it both with and without an index.

Comment: `select *` ? Recommend to be particular with columns and limit the results with a where clause.

Comment: @Kin exactly, but here we are ONLY testing the performance. The columns returned won't affect performance. I did not intend to suggest this SQL was ever used in production.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes help to find data, sure, so you may choose not to index small tables. They also have a role in data quality. For example, to ensure a value occurs in at most one row in a table, a unique index could be used. For these roles the index must be defined no matter the number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This statement [quoted in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135562/23721) is totally incorrect: **"Wide indexes, on the other hand, cover more queries"**

The wider the index is, the more specific it is to a set query rather than being usable across any query like a single-column index can be.

You must decide whether you are designing the database, or if you are redesigning the database every time a new query is written.